# MongoDB - Query on key name of an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm using laravel-mongodb.

I have a document in tree structure. I need to get documents for a specific year. Here is the image of how my data is:

[image]

I need to select all documents that have the period **2017**. my problem is that the period is a field of type object. And the value is the index. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([

/** As we need to filter on key but not on key's value,
 *  So convert periodos object to an array which makes {k : 2017, v : value of 2017} etc.. */
{
    $addFields: {
        periodos: {
            $objectToArray: "$periodos"
        }
    }
},
/** Filter docs to check periodos has 2017 */
{
    $match: {
        "periodos.k": "2017"
    }
},
/** convert periodos array back to object to its original type */
{
    $addFields: {
        periodos: {
            $arrayToObject: "$periodos"
        }
     }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQiMvsqR4bk)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator

```
db.collection.find({ "periodos.2017" : { $exists : true } })
```